# getter setter Maximum call stack size exceeded Error

Tags: javascript

I am trying to learn get and set in JavaScript object for that I tried

```
function ab(n){this.name=n;}; 
var c= new ab("abcde");  
console.log(c);
Object.defineProperty(c, 'name', {
    get: function() {
        return name;
    },
    set: function(Name) {
       this.name = Name;
        }
}); 
c.name="xyz";  
console.log(c.name);
```

Here I am first making object using constructor and then using get and set. But i am getting error "Maximum call stack size exceeded". I am not getting the reason of This Error . Thanks for help

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I think it has already been explained, that `this.name = Name` in the setter calls again the setter, wich leads to an infinite recursion.

How about this aproach:

```
function Ab(_name){
    Object.defineProperty(this, "name", {
        //enumerable: true, //maybe?
        get: function(){ return _name },
        set: function(value){ _name = value }
    });
}

var c = new Ab("abcde");
console.log(c, c.name);
```

Or the prototypal-approach
downside: the private property `_name` is a public

```
function Ab(n){
    this.name = n;
}
Object.defineProperty(Ab.prototype, "name", {
    get: function(){ return this._name },
    set: function(value){ this._name = value }
});
```

Or ES6
pretty much the same thing as the prototypal aproach

```
class Ab{
    constructor(n){
        this.name = n;
    }

    get name(){ return this._name },
    set name(value){ this._name = value }
}
```

Comment: the second and third approaches worked the best for my case, thanks for this answer!

Comment: This -> "leads to an infinite recursion". Make sure your getter is more than just "return this.myprop" e.g. "return 'MyProp: ' + this.myprop"

Answer (score 7):

The set syntax binds an object property to a function to be called when there is an attempt to set that property.

You dont need  to do `this.name = Name;`
inside set function.
This recursively triggers the setter causing stack overflow.
In fact you dont need a setter altogether in this case. Use setter only if, you have to do some extra work when the the property is set or modified.

[More](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set)

Answer (score 1):

You used `Object.defineProperty()` wrong. It should be called upon an uninitialized `Object`, `ab` in this case.

```
Object.defineProperty(ab, 'name', { //.. };
```

Comment: The code is  right. It is just that, he is setting the variable in the setter, triggering the setter again.

Answer (score 1):

You're naming your property (`name`) same as the backing field in the object that you're adding the property to. Additionally, `this` operator inside the `set` is referring to the wrong scope (specifically, it's scoped to the property, not the object); due to that, you're recursively setting the `name` property, causing a stack overflow exception.

You can modify your code as follows:

```
function myObject(n){ 
    this.nameValue = n;

    Object.defineProperty(this, 'name', {
         get: function() {
            return this.nameValue;
        },
        set: function(value) {
           this.nameValue = value;
        }
    }); 
}

var c = new myObject("foo");  
console.log(c.name);       //logs "foo"

c.name="bar";  
console.log(c.name);      //logs "bar"
```

The `this` keyword in `get` and `set` components of the `name` property now refers to the object defined by myObject function, because `Object.defineProperty` call is within that function.

Comment: You are just creating the accessor property inside the constructor. No need to even use defineProperty method.