# "Maximum call stack size exceeded" when I try to access data with a request from body (PATCH)

Tags: node.js, typescript, odata

I've got "Maximum call stack size exceeded" when I try to use `PATCH` or `PUT HTTP` request using @odata.body to access body data.

I've tried to make something similar with this PATCH request https://www.npmjs.com/package/odata-v4-server but it didn't work.
I've tried to change PATCH with PUT but still nothing.

```
import { ODataController, Edm, odata} from "odata-v4-server";
import { User } from "../model/User";
import "reflect-metadata";
import { ObjectID } from "mongodb";
import connection from "../connection";

@odata.type(User)
@Edm.EntitySet("User")
export class UsersController extends ODataController {
    @odata.GET
    async findOne(@odata.key key: string): Promise<User> {
        const connect = await connection();
        return connect.getRepository(User).findOne({_id:key});
    }
    @odata.POST
    async create():Promise<User>{
        const connect = await connection();
        var key = new ObjectID();
        return await connect.getRepository(User).save({_id: key.toString()});
    }
    @odata.PATCH
    async update(@odata.body delta:any){
        console.log(delta);
    }
    @odata.DELETE
    async remove(@odata.key key:string) {
        const connect = await connection();
        await connect.getRepository(User).delete({username:key})
    }
}
```

`GET, POST and DELETE` work fine but `PATCH` not.

Comment: Maybe worth googling it before hand: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37502163/getter-setter-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-error

Comment: I don't know how this helps me , I know what maximum call stack size exceeded is but i don't know why i get it. I just know where the problem is (when i use @odata.body because if i change odata.body with something else it work).

Comment: I think we can work it out. Might be because serialization issues with getters and setters with complex models class A has a property of type B and viceversa.