# How come assigning a property causes "Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded" error?

Tags: javascript, get, getter-setter, getter

I'm trying to better understand JavaScript `getter`s using Mozilla's documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get

I modified the code snippet in the article's IDE to this:

```
const obj = {
  get log() {
    return this.log = 1;
  }
};

console.log(obj.log);
```

and it worked, yielding this:

```
> 1
```

But when I try to separate out the `return` line to this:

```
const obj = {
  get log() {
    this.log = 1;
    return this.log;
  }
};

console.log(obj.log);
```

it errors out with:

```
Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

I can't figure out why these seemingly equivalent snippets of code would behave differently.  Any advice for a JavaScript newbie?

Thank you for your time

Update:
@CertainPerformance's answer cleared everything up for me.

I'm going to add the following example code to make it easier for me to understand in the future.

This is why the second version did not work:

```
const obj = {
  get log() {
    this.log = 100;
    return this.log; // will go back to line 2 `get log()`
  }
};

console.log(obj.log);
```

The first version works because it is calling the setter which returns the value assigned so no `getter` was recursively called.

If there is a reason to need the second version, then using a different property name will avoid the recursive calling.

```
const obj = {
  get log() {
    this._log = 100;
    return this._log;
  }
};

console.log(obj.log);
console.log(obj._log);
```

Comment: It's pretty much always a bad idea to use a getter or setter for a property that's also part of the getter because that creates a circular reference. If you get `x` you then have to get `x` which causes another get of `x`....etc.

Comment: As for your snippets - the first one just happens to not read the value of `log` which means it doesn't trigger `get log()` again. But it's still bad practice.

Comment: Also ,in your first code it returns 1 because you are doing something like `abc = 1;`, That will always return 1, You can change `this.log` to `this.xyz` too.

Comment: [Massive dupe](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+get+maximum+call+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: @TusharShahi sorry, I'm not understanding what you mean, but CertainPerformance's answer got me on the right direction.

Comment: Do abc = 1 in chrome console.

Comment: @TusharShahi gotcha...the assignment returns the value of the assignment.  That makes sense why the code ended up working.  Thank you 

Comment: @mplungjan sorry for the dupe.  I read through the other posts, but I wasn't able to understand it enough to make the connection.  I'm not sure if it's the way it's worded or the fact that they were discussing setters, whereas I was having trouble with the getter.  The answer and comments here was more direct and made more sense to me.  Either way, sorry about duplicating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `log` is a getter, but you have no associated setter, doing

```
return this.log = 1;
```

tries to access `log` as a setter (since it's a setter/getter property) - but no setter exists, so it'll either

- fail silently in sloppy mode
- throw an error in strict mode

```js
'use strict';
const obj = {
  get log() {
    return this.log = 1;
  }
};

console.log(obj.log);
```

In contrast, doing

```
return this.log;
```

invokes the *getter* on `log` too. But you're already in `log`'s getter, resulting in an infinite loop.

You probably want to use a different property name for the internal property and the external property - like `_log`, or with private fields, or something like that.

Comment: [Dupe with identical title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37502163/getter-setter-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-error) - [other dupes](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+get+maximum+call+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: @mplungjan not sure it's a complete dupe. OP is asking why one of the pieces of code works. The dupe only covers why the second one fails.

Comment: I am sure we can find the first part in the many other dupes.

Comment: @CertainPerformanc thank you for your solution and helping me understand where my logic went wrong.  Thank you again for your time 